# How to print a list without brackets and commas

Tags: python, list

I have a file,

```
6802496011442316593 1625090609  51048468525236  aaa=1111|bbbb=15|cccc=216|dddd=1625090604|eeee=5|ffff=12000|ggg=brtnrn=|hhhh=4|ii=lfp|ts=1625090609
6802496011442316593 1625090609  51048468525236  aaa=1111|bbbb=15|cccc=216|dddd=1625090604|eeee=5|ffff=12000|ggg=brtnrn=|hhhh=4|ii=lfp|ts=1625090489
6802496011442316593 1625090609  51048468525236  aaa=1111|bbbb=15|cccc=216|dddd=1625090604|eeee=5|ffff=12000|ggg=brtnrn=|hhhh=4|ii=lfp|ts=1625090549
6802496011442316593 1625090609  51048468525236  aaa=1111|bbbb=15|cccc=216|dddd=1625090604|eeee=5|ffff=12000|ggg=brtnrn=|hhhh=4|ii=lfp|ts=1625090599
6802496011442316593 1625090609  51048468525236  aaa=1111|bbbb=15|cccc=216|dddd=1625090604|eeee=5|ffff=12000|ggg=brtnrn=|hhhh=4|ii=lfp|ts=1625090599
```

from which I am extracting the last element "ts=1625090609" without "ts=":

```
with open(inputt, "r") as f1:
    for line in f1:
        exp=(line.split("\t")[3])
        params=(exp.split("|"))
        extraparamts=list()
        for param in params:
            if "ts=" in param:
                extraparamts.append(param[3:-1])
        print(extraparamts)
```

to list:

```
['1625090429']
['1625090489']
['1625090549']
['1625090599']
['1625090599']
```

and I want to print it in output without bracket and commas and in separate lines, like this:

```
1625090429
1625090489
1625090549
1625090599
1625090599
```

just to make it easier to sort and compare with same, but not sort file. Unfortunately it seems that

```
print(*tslist, sep=",")
```

does not work for me. Can you please tell me what am I doing wrong? I have tried itertools and

Comment: Why are you creating a *list of lists*? Currently you only have zero or one element in that inner list, so is there any real use for it?

Comment: Yeah you are right, rookie mistake, I've changed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Editing answer as per your edits , have added regex

```
import re

extraparamts = []
with open(inputt, "r") as f1:  
    f1 = f1.read()
    for line in f1.splitlines():  # you can ignore splitlines if your data does not require it
        if "ts" in line:
            matches = re.findall("ts.*", line)
            extraparamts.append(str(matches)[5:-5])
            
    

for data in extraparamts:
    print(data)
```

Will Give

```
1625090
1625090
1625090
1625090
1625090
```

Comment: Okay, but my list is differen - I've edited the post.

Comment: Yeah mate, thanks a lot! Just needed to change extraparamts.append(str(matches)[5:-5]) to extraparamts.append(str(matches)[5:-2]). Now I have to deal with memory exhausted for bigger file. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
print(*tslist[0].splitlines(), sep="\n")
```

Comment: Gives in output numbers in separate lines, but with [""]. Is there a chance to get rid off ['']?

Comment: Unfortunately nothing changed :( same output

Comment: @PublicQuip What does `print(tslist)` output?

Comment: [['1625090429'], ['1625090489'], ['1625090549'], ['1625090599'], ['1625090599']]

Comment: @PublicQuip What is does `print(type(tslist[0]))` give?

Comment: I have changed code and edited post - basicly I get rid off list of lists, now I have in output everything in separate lines, but again with ['']. print([i[0] for i in tslist], sep="\n") and print([i[0][0] for i in tslist], sep="\n")  gives me same in output - separate lines with ['1'] in each.

Comment: @PublicQuip What does `print(type(tslist[0]))` output?

Comment: now it gives me <class 'str'> each in separate lines

Comment: Nah, it just cut the number in each line. Like [''] is an element of list, not a value and I can't changed it.

Comment: @PublicQuip What does `print(tslist[0])` give?

Comment: ['250904']
['250904']
['250905']
['250905']
['250905']
each in separate line

Comment: Id does not - same result as in my previous comment. Like [''] is an element of list, not a value and I can't changed it.

Comment: @PublicQuip Edited my answer, please show me the result.

Answer (score 1):

### for lists

Try this:

```py
list = ['1625090429','1625090489','1625090549','1625090599','1625090599']
for item in list:
    print(item)
```

Output:

```
1625090429
1625090489
1625090549
1625090599
1625090599
```

### for lists in lists

Try this:

```py
list = [['1625090429'],['1625090489'],['1625090549'],['1625090599'],['1625090599']]
for item in list:
    for x in item:
        print(x)
```

Output:

```
1625090429
1625090489
1625090549
1625090599
1625090599
```

Comment: Okay, but my list is differen - I've edited the post.